# Why are top-rated, accepted answers being rendered below other answers?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, self-answer, sorting

See [Extreme wait-time when taking a SQL Server database offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808232/extreme-wait-time-when-taking-a-sql-server-database-offline/808334#808334)

The "best" answer is listed 5th on the page.

Comment: It's at the top for me. What are you sorting by?

Comment: I've seen this question two other times recently. Perhaps there is a bug in the default option somewhere? Note; it still is on "Votes" by default for me.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET That's my feeling too.  This item can't prove it one way or another, but perhaps in aggregate we'll discover the root cause.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: I've seen this type of question pop up from time to time, but I've yet to see any evidence that the order was changed by anything other than a misclick, mis-type (`o`-`a` does it if keyboard shortcuts are enabled) or simply having forgotten that they changed the order on a previous page. The frequency of reports is just too low to suspect a bug in the UI or preferences code.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thats quite possible, just seems odd that this exact problem has come up 3 times in the past 3 or so days. Could just be random of course.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: the keyboard shortcuts have been made part of the site proper rather recently; it was an add-on before. I suspect that with more people enabling it, mistyping while a tab with a question has focus is relatively easy and thus will be seen more now. You won't even notice the sort order changed if there are 0 or 1 answers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That is certainly a reasonable explanation of why more people are breaking it recently.

Answer (score 6):

You have the answer sort order set to *active*. Scroll back to the top and click on *votes*:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

The preference is saved; if you clicked on *active* on a different question, the setting persists and is used on all subsequent pages until you change it again.

If you have the keyboard shortcuts preference enabled, all it takes is typing <kbd>o</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> for you to set the ordering to active.

Comment: Interesting.  I didn't explicitly change it, although I'm willing to believe a misclick was involved.  The sort is on 'Active'.  Some of my peers noticed this one too, so I'm doubtful that we all changed our sort to 'active' of our own accord... but it's possible.

Comment: @JudeAllred: the sort preference is saved; you could have clicked on it on a different page.

Comment: I could have, but really it's just not something I do on SO.  If it was just me, I'd dismiss it as a misclick.  My team members noticed it too, so I'm suspicious.  But that's all.

Comment: Jude and I both have 4-digit user IDs on Stack Overflow, and both of us had sort=`Active`. I don't remember ever intentionally changing the sort order in my six years(!) on the site.

Comment: @JacobKrall: depending on what you looked at recently it could have taken a while for you to even notice.

Comment: I'd accept an answer of "The sort was on 'active'",  but given the lack of choice on my end, I'll dismiss any answer that says I sorted it myself.  Even if it ended up being a bug on my part (which I doubt, but am willing to accept), there's a ui quirk at play here.

Comment: @JudeAllred: I have not seen any evidence that there is a bug in the preference handling; this just hasn't been reported often enough. I added another way for this to happen; if you have keyboard shortcuts enabled all it takes is mis-typing `o` then `a`.

Comment: I've altered the phrasing and will accept once the timeout permits me.   That said, I think there's an interesting question in terms of if casual users would ever want to find themsleves sorting by something other than 'votes'.  Superusers, absolutely,  but the masses?

Comment: Mmm, edit battles.  Ok, I'll come back to this later.

Comment: @JudeAllred: I've been trying to accommodate your wording preference, but in my own words, as well as adding more information.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks, I appreciate that.  Regardless, I'll let this sit for a bit and see if anyone else chimes in to corroborate BradleyDotNET's comment.

Answer (score 2):

If you sort by "votes", the accepted answer is at the top.

If you sort by "oldest" or "active" it drops down.

> [image: sort by votes]

Comment: Good guy Oded. PRO Stack Overflow mod/developer. Still uses default red, size 1 brush in MS Paint :P

Comment: @Compass - that's how I roll